# Make takeEvery conditional on action.meta in redux sagas?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga that I only want to fire for certain `action.meta` values:

```
function* handleUpdateSomeStuff(action): Generator {
  if (action.meta === "Special_Meta") {
    // run some code
  }
}

function* myConditionalSaga(): Generator {
  yield takeEvery(
    [ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_STUFF],
    handleUpdateSomeStuff
  );
}

function* itemSaga(): Generator {
  yield all([
    fork(myConditionalSaga),
    // ... more sagas
  ]);
}
```

Currently, I check within `handleUpdateSomeStuff` whether or not `action.meta` meets a certain condition.  But I feel like the code should never even get that far.  However, I don't see how the `action` argument might be available in `myConditionalSaga` to check it there.  I am thinking something like this:

```
function* myConditionalSaga(action): Generator {
  if (action.meta === "Special_Meta") {
    yield takeEvery(
      [ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_STUFF],
      handleUpdateSomeStuff
    );
  }
}
```

The above block is more meta code than anything else, as trying to pass an argument to `myConditionalSaga` gives a TS error `Argument of type '(action: any) => Generator<unknown, any, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.` inside the `fork` statement.

Is there a way to prevent `handleUpdateSomeStuff` from being called based on the `action.meta` of the action?  I did indeed read [Redux-saga takeLatest conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822849/redux-saga-takelatest-conditionally), as well as [the docs on takeEvery](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args), but I am struggling to undertsand how that may be applied to my scenario to get the desired result.

<sub>Opinions welcome in comments: Should I not even worry about it?  Just let the function call reach `myConditionalSaga` and handle the `if` there?</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` and its variants support a function as its first argument instead of an action type (or array of action types).

So you should be able to do something like this:

```js
function* handleUpdateSomeStuff(action): Generator {
  // this runs only for when meta is "Special_Meta"
}

function* myConditionalSaga(): Generator {
  yield takeEvery(action => {
    return (
      action.type === ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_STUFF &&
      action.meta === "Special_Meta"
    );
  }, handleUpdateSomeStuff);
}
```

It might seem bit "wordy" like this, but if you need to limit the handlers based on the meta param more often, you can of course create some utility helper, e.g.:

```js
const typeAndMeta = (type, meta) => action => action.type === type && action.meta === meta
yield takeEvery(typeAndMeta(ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_STUFF, 'Special_Meta'), saga);
```

or even

```js
const takeEveryByMeta = (type, meta, saga, ...args) => {
    return takeEvery(action => action.type === type && action.meta === meta, saga, ...args);
}
yield takeEveryByMeta(ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_STUFF, 'Special_Meta', saga);
```

You can easily extend these helpers to support array of types/meta values as well.